# UINavigationController strange crash

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having a strange problem with my UINavigationController. the stacktraces are:

[image: trace]

which is very odd to me because all I did was:

```
CommonVC* cvc = [[CommonVC alloc] init];
//CommonVC is my customized viewController. and i did some setting after the init.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:TRUE];
[cvc release];
```

and after 3 times pushing and popping it crashes.
i also ran it with NSZombie but it told the zombie is the CommonVC itself.

[image]

so can anyone help me find where the problem would be?

Comment: Your code looks fine - the error must be somewhere inside your CommonVC class - I would guess you're not retaining something important!

Comment: would that cause the CommonVC to be zombie but something inside?

Comment: Don't know - depends on what your CommonVC has inside it - you might have some sort or retain loop preventing any object from being released :)

Comment: well then there should be no zombie but leak right?

Comment: You need to post more code - what you have in your question at the moment is correct! I don't know how it defines a Zombie so without more info I can't help any more :(

Comment: how you are calling the method ?

Comment: and also the called method name ?

Comment: Do you make use of delegates and set them in your view controller. If yes check if they are made nil...

Comment: I am not sure if this could be the problem, but you could try to use ...animated: YES]; instead of ...animated: TRUE];.

Comment: Thank you @7KV7. i set the delegate twice when another CommonVC is pushed into navigationController. will you get my bounty if your answer is in comment?

Comment: @boreas: I will make it as an answer. You can accept it then and award the bounty

Comment: Post the `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear:` code of `CommonVC` as what you have posted is not the issue. Also @dasdom: **TRUE/FALSE**, **0/1** and **YES/NO** are all acceptable values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you make use of delegates and set them in your view controller. If yes check if they are made nil...

Comment: @boreas: I did not get the bounty till now :(

Comment: sorry last time it did not allow me to award the bounty due to some time limit issue. now it's yours and thank you for the help:)